# Is it possible to place a CAGradientLayer under the background layer?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I'm adding a gradient layer to a custom button, the `this` reference in the following code:

```
//a custom gradient
var layerGradient = new CAGradientLayer();

//the gradient colors are the base color to the modified version
layerGradient.Colors = new CGColor[]{color.CGColor, color2.CGColor};

//add the gradient as a sublayer in the button
this.Layer.InsertSublayer(layerGradient, 0);
```

This works fine and the gradient does what it should.  But, if the button has a background image, the background doesn't display.  The gradient appears to be on a layer above the background, obscuring it.  Is there any way to fix this, or do I need to draw the background on my own layer and add it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding the background image as its own layer, and then adding the gradient layer below it:

```
mImageView = new UIImageView();
this.Layer.InsertSublayer(mImageView.Layer, 0);
mImageView.Image = mImage;
```

So this makes a UIImageView layer to hold the image.  And then I call the code as in my question to insert the gradient layer **underneath** this ImageView layer and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it but possibly `insertSublayer:below:` is what you are looking for.

```
- (void)insertSublayer:(CALayer *)aLayer below:(CALayer *)sublayer
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because simply calling setBackgroundImage doesn't appear to create any layers; after I do this, the SubLayers collection is still null.  But I figured out a workaround; see my answer to the question.